# Bootstrap 3 and FancyBox2: Nav arrows not showing on first photo in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox-2

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with FancyBox2 and my [demo site is here](http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/gallery.php). Everything works great except that there are **NO** navigation arrows on the first photo in the photo gallery. All the other photos have their nav arrows. Anyone have any clues as to why?

Here's the first photo code with the second photo code. As you can see, the code is nearly identical.

```
            <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="lightbox" href="http://placehold.it/400x400.png">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="First title here" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
                <div class="text-center">
                    <small class="text-muted">Image Title</small>
                </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
            </a>


            <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/400x400.png">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="second title here" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
                <div class="text-center">
                    <small class="text-muted">Image Title</small>
                </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
            </a>
```

However, when I view the code on the server using Developer Tools, I can see that the arrows seem to be dynamically added through javascript (I could be wrong). For some reason it is not dynamically added to the first photo.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced the first photo code with the second photo code and it works fine...still don't know what the problem was, oh well. But, it works.